# Issues with 8021q while installing vlan

Tags: networking, raspberrypi, 21.10, vlan

I am having issues using the vlan package on Ubuntu Server installed on a Raspberry Pi 4. I am running Ubuntu 21.10.

I will run the command `sudo apt install vlan` and the package will download. When I run `sudo modprobe 8021q` I am getting this error

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8021q not found in directory /lib/modules/5.13.0-1015-raspi
```

I have done research on this error and have not found anything that has helped. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Same problem here. "sudo depmod" does not fix this. It seems that this is a bug:
https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5968804.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the package `linux-modules-extra-raspi`:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi
```

The [21.10 release notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-notes/21951) briefly call out that some kernel modules have been moved to this package (including apparently 8021q).

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!  Been trying to get this to work for about 5 hours now.  Installed the extras, and voila!  I now have vlans working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to (re)generate module dependency list and check modprobe once again. Whole installation sequence is:

```
sudo apt-get install vlan 
lsmod | grep 8021q
grep 8021q /etc/modules
sudo echo "8021q" >> /etc/modules
sudo modprobe 8021q
grep 8021q /etc/modules
```

Possible way how to fix missing modules:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-5.13.0-1015-raspi
```

Check directory content of:
`/lib/modules/`

`/lib/modules/5.13.0-1015-raspi`

`/lib/modules/5.13.0-1015-raspi/kernel/net`